# RGBs and Potentiometers

Tags: arduino-uno

I think my if statement can't be read here in my program. The RGBs should light up and change color when the potentiometer is turned but instead the RGBs just light up immediately and change color simultaneously. How do I fix this?

```
int POT1=A0;
int POT2=A1;
int POT3=A2;
int Red1=9;
int Green1=10;
int Blue1=11;
int Red2=3;
int Green2=5;
int Blue2=6;
int sValue1=0;
int sValue2=0;
int sValue3=0;
int oValue1=0;
int oValue2=0;
int oValue3=0;
int value1=0;
int value2=0;
int value3=0;
int timer(250);

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(Red1,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(Green1,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(Blue1,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(Red2,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(Green2,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(Blue2,OUTPUT); 

}

void loop() {

sValue1=analogRead(POT1);
sValue2=analogRead(POT2);
sValue3=analogRead(POT3);

oValue1=map(sValue1,0,1023,0,255);
oValue2=map(sValue2,0,1023,0,255);
oValue3=map(sValue3,0,1023,0,255);

if ((sValue1<=127)&&(sValue2<=127)&&(sValue3<=127));
{
  setColor1(0,255,255); //red
  setColor2(255,255,0); //blue
  delay(timer);
  value1=0;
  value2=0;
  value3=0;

}

if ((sValue1<=127)&&(sValue2<=127)&&(sValue3>127));
{
  setColor1(255,255,0); //blue
  delay(timer);
  setColor2(255,0,255); //green
  delay(timer);
  value1=0;
  value2=0;
  value3=1;
}

if ((sValue1<=127)&&(sValue2>127)&&(sValue3<=127));
{
  setColor1(255,0,255); //green
  delay(timer);
  setColor2(0,255,255); //red
  delay(timer);
  value1=0;
  value2=1;
  value3=0;
}

if ((sValue1<=127)&&(sValue2>127)&&(sValue3>127));
{
  setColor1(0,255,255); //red
  delay(timer);
  setColor2(255,0,255); //green
  delay(timer);
  value1=0;
  value2=1;
  value3=1;
}

Serial.print("POT 1=");
Serial.print(value1);
Serial.print("\t POT 2=");
Serial.print(value2);
Serial.print("\t POT 3=");
Serial.print(value3);

if ((value1==0)&&(value2==0)&&(value3==0))
{
 Serial.print("\t RGB1=");
 Serial.print("RED");
 Serial.print("\t RGB2=");
 Serial.print("BLUE"); 
}

else if ((value1==0)&&(value2==0)&&(value3==1))
{
  Serial.print("\t RGB1=");
  Serial.print("BLUE");
  Serial.print("\t RGB2=");
  Serial.println("GREEN");
  Serial.println(" ");
}

else if ((value1==0)&&(value2==1)&&(value3==0))
{
  Serial.print("\t RGB1=");
  Serial.print("GREEN");
  Serial.print("\t RGB2=");
  Serial.println("RED");
  Serial.println(" ");
}

else if ((value1==0)&&(value2==1)&&(value3==1))
{
  Serial.print("\t RGB1=");
  Serial.print("RED");
  Serial.print("\t RGB2=");
  Serial.println("GREEN");
  Serial.println(" ");
}

}

void setColor1(int red1, int green1, int blue1){
  {
    analogWrite(Red1,red1);
    analogWrite(Green1,green1);
    analogWrite(Blue1,blue1);
  }
}



void setColor2(int red2, int green2, int blue2){
  {
    analogWrite(Red2,red2);
    analogWrite(Green2,green2);
    analogWrite(Blue2,blue2);

  }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is more complex than your description.  Assuming you copied and pasted it, try simplifying it.  You only need a few lines to change the color of the LEDs based on the position of a potentiometer.  Include either a description of your hardware connections, a schematic or a clear picture of your wiring. Then edit this question.

Comment: By the way, why not just use your pot values (scaled to 0-255) to set the red, green, and blue channels of your LEDs directly?

Comment: How do I do that?????

Answer (score 0):

I haven't traced through your if statement logic in detail to see what you are trying to do, BECAUSE I found that you have statements like this:

```
//            Get rid of this semicolon in every if statement.
//            |
//            V
if (condition); {
    //        ^
    //        |

    //Code that will always be executed
}
```

You should **NOT** have a semicolon after an if statement like that. That says "if (condition) then do nothing" (A semicolon creates a blank "do-nothing" statement that becomes the code that is executed if the if statement is true. Then the code in the braces gets executed every time.)

It is parsed as:

```
if (condition) <empty_statement;> 

{
    code that always executes
}
```

That is one of the hidden "nasties" of C and it's close cousins like C++, Java, and Objective-C. Another nasty is typing:

```
if (a=b)
```

...when you mean `if (a==b)`. (The first version puts the value of b into a, and then evaluates b as a boolean. If it's 0, the if statement is treated as false. If it's non-zero, the if statement is evaluated as true.

Another one is the fall-through cases in C `switch` statements. If you forget to add a `break` statement at the end of each case it falls through to the next case.